# Read folder names in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux

I want to read the folder names in a specific directory and create a dropdown list with the names.
All files and folders are stored on a debian web-server (nginx, php5).
Actual I do this with php, but I don't know much about php, so I want to do this with Javascript. The php code looks like:

```
<?php
     foreach(glob('auswertung/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
        $dir = str_replace('auswertung/', '', $dir);
        $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'standard');
        $files = glob("auswertung/$dir/_*");
        if (!in_array($dir, $blacklist)){

             $dirSmall = substr($dir,0,10);
             $datum = date('d.m.Y - H:i:s', $dirSmall);
             foreach ($files as $file){
                 $file = str_replace("auswertung/$dir/_", '', $file);
                 $file_utf8 = utf8_encode($file );
                 $von = array("ä","ö","ü","ß","Ä","Ö","Ü"," ","é");  //to correct double whitepaces as well
                 $zu  = array("&auml;","&ouml;","&uuml;","&szlig;","&Auml;","&Ouml;","&Uuml;","&nbsp;","&#233;");  
                 $file2 = str_replace($von, $zu, $file_utf8);
              }
              echo '<option value="'.$dir.'">'.$datum." - ".$file2."</option>\n";

         }
     }
?>
```

The folders names are formated in Unix Timestamp, like 1413893713034, 1414926421959 ...
Is it possible to do this in Javascript, because I have problems to combine HTML, Javascript and PHP?

Comment: Server side? I don't know how much folder manipulation you can do client side with javascript. I think it's pretty well sandboxed on the client as a security measure.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write the javascript?  What did you try?  I what way did it fail?

Comment: On this point no, because I found nothing about how to get the folder names with javascript. I have already a functional google map, with API V3. I have many datasets which I will choose with the dropdown list. With the php code it works sometimes, but not allways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the short answer is No. You must use server-side language (such as PHP) to access the file system of the server.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said Javascript is loaded on a Client web page, it cannot directly access the server file structure.

However you can "load" an Ajax response from a Server-Side page (like php or others) and then work with those Strings in the way you desire.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you can't do this on client side. The most elegant solution to achieve this is through AJAX. Do you need a simple example of this?